# sudo apt update says things i dont know how to fix

Tags: 20.04

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IDDu.png

when I update it says these things in the above image

how do I fix this? My ubuntu version 20.04.3

ask me if you need any more info about my system

thanks for any help or tags to add to the question

Comment: Can you please [edit] and provide the screenshot of `software-properties-gtk` app with the opened tab as "Other Sources".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Is that a screenshot of a terminal windows? Can you copy/paste the text output itself insted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

By going through the screenshot I think,  `apt` is telling us that the following keys are missing `76F1A20FF897672F` and `7373B12CCE03BEB4B`. To add these keys, run the following commands:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 76F1A20FF897672F`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7373B12CCE03BEB4B`

for more : go through this [blog post](https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/)

If you are facing errors still such as , `no release file found` and `repository is not signed`. Then you can try to remove those problematic PPAs. this [blog post](https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/how-to-fix-the-repository-is-not-signed-error-on-ubuntu-20-04/) explains the process of removing those PPAs and run `sudo apt update` again

Comment: didn't work the first command just said:-     
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.NwB0bnkDkQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 76F1A20FF897672F
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
and second one just said:-     
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.E4Sx8fwDMi/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7373B12CCE03BEB4B
gpg: "7373B12CCE03BEB4B" not a key ID: skipping
the rest i am still working on ill get back to you on that thanks for your help